# Shuffling in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to shuffle an array of functions in python. My code goes like this:

```
import random

def func1():
    ...

def func2():
    ...

def func3():
    ...

x=[func1,func2,func3]
y=random.shuffle(x)
```

And I think it might be working, the thing is that I don't know how to call the functions after I shuffle the array!

if I write "y" after the last line, it doesn't do anything!

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Are you trying to call all of the functions, in random order?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, [`random.shuffle()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) shuffles the list in place. It does not return the shuffled list, so `y = None`. That is why it does nothing when you type `y`.

To call each function, you can loop through `x` and call each function like so:

```
for function in x:
    function() # The parentheses call the function
```

Lastly, your functions actually produce a SyntaxError. If you want them to do nothing, add [`pass`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) at the end of them. `pass` does absolutely nothing and is put where python expects something.

---

So altogether:

```
def func1():
    pass

def func2():
    pass

def func3():
    pass

x = [func1, func2, func3]
random.shuffle(x)
for function in x:
    function()
```

Comment: testing. testing testing.

Comment: @Estefania: Consider accepting this answer by clicking the check-mark below the voting buttons on the left.